# How i export some columns from file .csv in Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I have this CSV file with name `peco1.csv` and I need to use Perl to separate only the first seven columns for another CSV file

#### peco1.csv

```
Hour;peco1In;peco1Out;peco1WorkTime;peco2In;peco2Out;peco2WorkTime;peco3In;peco3Out;peco3WorkTime;peco4In;peco4Out;peco4WorkTime;peco5In;peco5Out;peco5WorkTime;peco6In;peco6Out;peco6WorkTime;peco7In;peco7Out;peco7WorkTime;peco8In;peco8Out;peco8WorkTime
10;26;31;100;26;19;100
11;30;43;100;48;27;100
12;26;35;100;36;27;100
13;26;41;100;41;25;100
14;32;43;100;57;32;100
15;23;44;100;77;60;100
16;44;48;100;59;42;100
17;60;67;100;52;49;100
18;35;56;100;48;39;100
19;39;48;100;58;37;100
20;18;29;100;28;30;100
21;24;26;100;16;14;100
22;18;13;100;10;3;100
23;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

And I execute this in command line of Windows

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -e "my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();while(my $row = $csv->getline(ARGV)){$csv->print(STDOUT, [@$row[0,2,3]])}" peco1.csv > new.csv
```

How can I show only the first seven columns?

Like this result:

```
Hour;peco1In;peco1Out;peco1WorkTime;peco2In;peco2Out;peco2WorkTime
10;26;31;100;26;19;100
11;30;43;100;48;27;100
12;26;35;100;36;27;100
13;26;41;100;41;25;100
14;32;43;100;57;32;100
15;23;44;100;77;60;100
16;44;48;100;59;42;100
17;60;67;100;52;49;100
18;35;56;100;48;39;100
19;39;48;100;58;37;100
20;18;29;100;28;30;100
21;24;26;100;16;14;100
22;18;13;100;10;3;100
23;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

Comment: only the first 7 columns of csv

Comment: yes, can you help me?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `print "Hour;peco1In;peco1Out;peco1WorkTime;peco2In;peco2Out;peco2WorkTime\n"`?

Comment: because is to run with other files with other values

Comment: It's very disappointing that the only effort you seem to have made is to find a Perl one-liner that does something comparable to your own needs, and copy it into a Stack Overflow question. Don't you think you could have done something more than rely on the internet for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have done is to find an example of something similar and applied it to your own data without changing it. It's clear that your one-liner copies the first, third, and fourth columns from the input file, which is nothing to do with your own requirement. It also uses all the default options for `Text::CSV_XS`, which include using a comma `,` for the separator character. You are using semicolons `;` so it is highly unlikely to work as it stands

This program seems to do what you require. If you save it as, say, `7col_csv.pl` then you can run it as

```
perl 7col_csv.pl peco1.csv > new.csv
```

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary   => 1,
    sep_char => ';',
    eol      => $/,
});

while ( my $row = $csv->getline(\*ARGV)) {
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, [ @$row[0 .. 6] ] );
}
```

#### output

```
Hour;peco1In;peco1Out;peco1WorkTime;peco2In;peco2Out;peco2WorkTime
10;26;31;100;26;19;100
11;30;43;100;48;27;100
12;26;35;100;36;27;100
13;26;41;100;41;25;100
14;32;43;100;57;32;100
15;23;44;100;77;60;100
16;44;48;100;59;42;100
17;60;67;100;52;49;100
18;35;56;100;48;39;100
19;39;48;100;58;37;100
20;18;29;100;28;30;100
21;24;26;100;16;14;100
22;18;13;100;10;3;100
23;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Text files generally end at the end, and you shouldn't have to worry yourself about placing and end of file. Please explain what you mean by *"this works good but not stop"*. What result are you getting that you don't want?

Comment: when i run this in windows cmd don´t stop... i need press ctrl+C to stop

Comment: Have you run the program according to the command line I showed at the top? Is `peco1.csv` an ordinary static file, or are you using a pipe? If I use the data that you showed in your question then my solution runs and produces the output I have shown. You need to tell me what may be different about your situation that causes it to run endlessly, otherwise I can't help

Comment: the result file is ok and all off the data is good but don't stop... i don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

since you only want to trim the header line then that isn't too bad.

```
my $infile = 'peco1.csv';

open(my $fh, "<", $infile) or die "Can't open file!";
my @head = ();
my $newHead = '';
while (<$fh>){
     chomp;
     if ($_ =~ m/'Hour'/){
          @head = split(';' , $_);
          @head = splice(@head, 0, 7);
          $newHead = join(';', @head);
          print("newHead\n");
     }
     else{
          print("$_\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: It is best to declare all of your variables as *late* as possible, rather than writing a block of declarations at the top of your code, like old-fashioned C. It's also best to avoid Python-style identifers, so a name like `$newHead` should look like `$new_head`. The declaration of both `@head` and `$new_head` should be *inside* the first `if` block. Also, the test should probably be `if ( $. == 1 )` rather than checking the contents of the line